# Default retrieve order in oracle possible?

Tags: mysql, database, oracle

Lets assume that i create a table and perform the following inserts :

```
insert mango,4
insert apple,1
insert pear,3
insert banana,2
```

When performing : `select fruit, id from fruit_table` . The following result is given :

```
**fruit    id**
apple    1
pear     3
mango    4
banana   2
...
```

This is different from the way that they were originally inserted. Without using `order by` is there a way to specify (perhaps when creating the table, or performing the insert) that the position is relative to their insertion?. So when doing `select fruit, id from fruit_table`, i would get the records in the order that they were inserted.

Comment: you can add a column inserted_at to fruit_table and record the inserted time i.e sysdate. Then order by inserted_at.

Comment: There are many ways to do this however for this purpose I would like to know if it is possible to set the order to 'default' without specifying in the query 'order by'.

Comment: no, I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle you can define a view over the table with an ORDER BY.

```
create table fruit_table (
  id number,
  name varchar2(30));

create view  fruit
as
select *
from   fruit_table
order by id;


insert into fruit values (4,'mango');
insert into fruit values (1,'apple');
insert into fruit values (3,'pear');
insert into fruit values (2,'banana');

select * from fruit_table;

select * from fruit;
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1b24f/1

I can't think of a situation where this would be a good idea, and I wouldn't trust it to be foolproof for anything other than trivial situations.